# If a motherboard has onboard graphics, can I use a monitor for BIOS

Tags: command-line, motherboard, bios, integrated-graphics

I am building a home server that will run FreeNAS with a Plex media server plugin, and will only ever plug it into a monitor to do the initial command line setup. If I get a mother board like this [ASRock FM2A88M](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157571) that has an on board video chip set, will I be able to get into BIOS and a command line with a processor such as an [AMD Athlon X4 860K](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/amd-cpu-ad860kxbjabox) that has no integrated graphics, and no video card? Basically, with the above motherboard, and no video card, which processor do I need in order to be able to plug in a monitor and access BIOS and a command line: one with integrated graphics, or one without?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the motherboard has a built-in graphics then you can use that for BIOS and whatever OS you run.

If the CPU has built-in graphics then the motherboard need to support CPU-based graphics and give a physical connector for you to plug your monitor into.

From what I can see, the ASRock FM2A88M has AMD Radeon R7/R5 Series Graphics in A-series APU and that should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have an MSI A88X-G43 board with an 860K processor & have no graphics. I did order a cheaper processor to show bios so I can update it since it's probably an old revision. As it stands, I have no graphics. As for this board, either the video is gone & the board is no good, or it's a bios issue. It's best to keep the motherboard bios updated, rather to be in a position like this.